# I'm trying to calculate the average score in a dictionary, but instead, it returns the average as zero for each student

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the average score in a dictionary, but instead, it returns the average as zero for each student

COED :

```
def student_avrage(student_l):
     lib = {}
     for i in student_l:
         if i[0] in lib.keys():
             lib[i[0]].append(int(i[1]))
     else:
             lib[i[0]] = [int(i[1])]
     totle_score =0
     for key, value in lib.items():
             if len(value) > 1:
                 for itm in value:
                     totle_score += itm
            quantityofscore =  len(value)
            avrage = totle_score/quantityofscore
            lib[key] = [avrage]
    print(lib)
```

student_l = [["Ali", 20], ["Bion", 25], ["Jack", "30"], ["Diane", "50"]]
student_avrage(student_l)

OUTCOME:

```
{'Ali': [0.0], 'Bion': [0.0], 'Jack': [0.0], 'Diane': [0.0]}
```

Comment: please fix your indentation. And don't use the name `inputDict` for what is in fact a (nested) list, not a dict.

Comment: some of your entries in `inputDict` are strings ("30" and "50") and the other two are normal numbers. this is prone to cause trouble

Comment: @RobinZigmond Would please tell me where is the defected indentation? and I changed the "inputDict" to "student_l", and it still returns similar results

Comment: @sulaimanalomayri it looks like you haven't indented any of the body of the function `student_avrage`. But just paste in the exact code you have - Python wouldn't run the code with the indentation you've shown here.

Comment: @KenHBS I'm suppose to work with this kind of array. Also, I converted the string items to int in my first IF statment

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when a student doesn't have more than one score, since you have an `if len(value) > 1`

the below should solve this for you

```
inputDict = [["Ali", 20],["Bion",25],["Jack",30],["Diane",50]]
def student_avrage(inputDict):
    dic = {}
    for i in inputDict:
        if i[0] in dic.keys():
            dic[i[0]].append(int(i[1]))
        else:
            dic[i[0]] = [int(i[1])]
    return dic

dic = student_avrage(inputDict)

for key, value in dic.items():
    totle_score = 0
    # this bit here needs to go
    # if len(value) > 1:
    for itm in value:
        totle_score += int(itm)
    quantityofscore =  len(value)
    avrage = totle_score/quantityofscore
    dic[key] = [avrage]
print(dic)
```

with the output of:
`{'Ali': [20.0], 'Bion': [25.0], 'Jack': [30.0], 'Diane': [50.0]}`

Comment: I believe you're right, but when I paste the code and run it, returns an error and points at " dic.items():" in the second IF statement that it's not defined

Comment: @sulaimanalomayri sorry for that, I've edited the code to return the dictionary when calling the function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this `if` statement:

```
if len(value) > 1:
```

In your example all of these `value` lists will have length exactly one. The result is that you never loop over them and add the values to the total, which is initialised at `0`. So this is why your total (and hence your average) is coming out at 0.

Just remove the `if` statement and I think you should be fine. (Although I haven't tried the code, so it's possible there are other problems.)

Oh, and as @KenHBS says in his comment, make sure all your values are `int`s, or convert them to `int`s before trying to add them.